# How to capture type variable in TemplateHaskell quote

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to write a Lift instance that lifts not only the constructor, but also its type variables.
For example, take `Proxy a`. I need a `Lift` instance such that, when `lift (Proxy @Int)` is spliced, GHC will correctly infer than the generated expression is a `Proxy Int`.

```
-- GHC should infer that x :: Proxy Int
x = $(TH.lift (Proxy @Int))
```

I tried this:

```
instance Lift (Proxy a) where
  lift _ = [|Proxy @a|]

x = $(TH.lift (Proxy @Int))
```

It seems TH captured `a` and not `Int` as expected.
I'm not sure what else to try

```
/.../TH/Test.hs:15:7: error:
    • The exact Name ‘a’ is not in scope
        Probable cause: you used a unique Template Haskell name (NameU), 
        perhaps via newName, but did not bind it
        If that's it, then -ddump-splices might be useful
```

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect. Quotes use `Lift` for variables of a particular type, not literal constructors. The basic pattern is fine.

Comment: Is it actually important to generate a type application? I don't think it's possible to make that work with an unknown type. It seems like you have the problem that the outer type variable no longer exists when the splice is generated, so there's nothing for it to refer to. There are workarounds, but they require giving up in the `Lift` class.

Comment: Ah, the `Lift` class can work, if you give up on type applications.

Comment: Using type applications is not required. Here's a repro closer to my actual use case: https://gist.github.com/dcastro/20175fdbf2e43a77c9504d98e9fa3c36

Comment: Also, for anyone else reading this ticket, it seems this issue has been brought up with the GHC team, see [this](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/17565) and [this](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/207)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template-haskell doesn't seem to provide anything like that. But there might be a solution that you can implement from scratch. The idea is to define a class to carry a quote representing each type:

```hs
class TLift a where
  tlift :: Q Type
```

For instance:

```hs
instance TLift Int where
  tlift = [t|Int|]

-- and so on
```

Then to define a quote featuring a type application:

```
proxyQ :: forall a. TLift a => Q Exp
proxyQ = [|Proxy @( $(tlift @a) )|]
```

One limitation here is that `TLift` instances can only produce quotes for completely concrete types, no type variables. Maybe [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) can work around that.

Comment: Ah, it seems Matthew Pickering has suggested [something like this before](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/207), though it was rejected. He called it `LiftT`, and proposed instances of `LiftT` should be automatically generated by GHC. Your suggestion seems to be the closest we can get to that at the moment, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this can't be done with a direct reference to the type in order to use type applications. By the time the spliced code makes a reference to `a`, the scope in which it was defined no longer exists.

But I believe this is one of the known issues that led to the creation of typed template Haskell. And that can be used to solve this.  Note that GHC 8.10 introduced an additional entry in the class, `liftTyped`, which can solve this directly.  But it also provides the hint needed to use this on earlier versions of GHC, which is that `lift x === unTypeQ (liftTyped x)`.

From that, I could see how to write an instance of `Lift` for `Proxy a` for versions of GHC older than 8.10.

```
instance Lift (Proxy a) where
    lift x = unTypeQ (helper x)
      where
        helper :: Proxy b -> Q (TExp (Proxy b))
        helper _ = [|| Proxy ||]
```

For GHC 8.10, this would just be

```
instance Lift (Proxy a) where
    liftTyped _ = [|| Proxy ||]
```

Honestly, there are a bunch of `Lift` instances seemingly missing. This is just one of the more indirect ones to write, at least before GHC 8.10.

Comment: The `unTypeQ` doesn't seem to work, GHC still infers `x :: Proxy a`. Here's a different repro, closer to my actual use case: https://gist.github.com/dcastro/20175fdbf2e43a77c9504d98e9fa3c36

Comment: In other words, if the constructor uses a phantom data type and packs a typeclass dict, the lifted expression required a type annotation or type application to compile. But 
`unTypeQ` removes all the typing information we need.